# Gradle Application Plugin - Not generate the windows start script?

Tags: plugins, gradle

When the gradle application plugin generates the startScripts, it generates for both windows and linux. Is there a way to exclude the windows script from going to bin/ when running distZip task?

Comment: AFAICT this isn't configurable. If you dislike them so much, why not just delete them after running `startScripts`?

Answer (score 6):

It's possible to delete windows script in the `doLast` block of the `startScrips` task, as:

```
startScripts {
    doLast {
        delete windowsScript
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best option that I've found. Tested in Gradle v5.6.4.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `startScripts.enabled = false` in your build.gradle file. Tested with gradle 3.4

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to define an `exclude` spec for the `distZip` task in `build.gradle` as follows:

```
distZip.exclude "**/*.bat"
```

This will exclude all `.bat` files from the zip distribution.